# Can't seem to show CSS Animation iteration examples

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I came across a codepen example that allows me to iterate through various div elements ([link to example](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/PoKMyWE). I want to add more items to the list. I added extra divs and gave them the respected class name sequence numbers, but they don't show up. I've also listed the HTML and CSS code below.

Do you have any idea why?

```
<h1>
  <span>always be</span>
  <div class="message">
    <div class="word1">close</div>
    <div class="word2">code</div>
    <div class="word3">creating</div>
    <div class="word4">times</div>
  </div>
</h1>
```

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
h1 {
  color: #333;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 550px;
}

h1 span {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.message {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 900;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  top: 0.2rem;
  left: 270px;
  animation: openclose 5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.word1, .word2, .word3 {
  font-family: tahoma;
}

@keyframes openclose {
  0% {
    top: 0.2rem;
    width: 0;
  }
  5% {
    width: 0;
  }
  15% {
    width: 230px;
  }
  30% {
    top: 0.2rem;
    width: 230px;
  }
  33% {
    top: 0.2rem;
    width: 0;
  }
  35% {
    top: 0.2rem;
    width: 0;
  }
  38% {
    top: -4.5rem;
    
  }
  48% {
    top: -4.5rem;
    width: 190px;
  }
  62% {
    top: -4.5rem;
    width: 190px;
  }
  66% {
    top: -4.5rem;
    width: 0;
    text-indent: 0;
  }
  71% {
    top: -9rem;
    width: 0;
    text-indent: 5px;
  }
  86% {
    top: -9rem;
    width: 285px;
  }
  95% {
    top: -9rem;
    width: 285px;
  }
  98% {
    top: -9rem;
    width: 0;
    text-indent: 5px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    text-indent: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Look closely at the keyframes. They go from 0 width to something just three times. It’s a pretty non general way of doing things.